# Any way to guarantee all tasks will be attempted with Task Parallel library?

Tags: .net, multithreading, exception, task-parallel-library

This is actually a question of my own in response to my answer to [Circular dependency with cross-cutting concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729907/circular-dependency-with-cross-cutting-concern/17731370#17731370)

Is there a variant of `Parallel.ForEach` that at least guarantees that every possible Task will at least be *attempted* regardless if any particular task throws an exception?

I realize I can wrap each task in it's own `try`/`catch`/`finally`, etc, (either directly or indirectly) and maybe use some synchronized container save the exceptions, or something, but that seems like a lot of work--with many possible solutions to evaluate--work I would think might be better for the Task Parallel library to handle.

My trials of throwing exceptions within tasks seem to suggest that `Parallel.ForEach` might abort in the middle and cancel any remaining tasks).  The situation seems similar for `{some enumerable}.AsParallel().ForAll({the task});`.  I think the strategy of aborting remaining tasks -- or aborting before creating the remaining tasks, as it might be--is a perfectly acceptable behavior in some circumstances.  However, sometimes, *tasks are going to die*, and it is best that we attempt running as many tasks as we can and keep track of which ones survived and which ones died.

I so see [How to handle all unhandled exceptions when using Task Parallel Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707295/how-to-handle-all-unhandled-exceptions-when-using-task-parallel-library) but its not clear to me if that answer my question.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/31/9674669.aspx <= might also be related.

This is not any high priority question for me, I just thought I'd throw it out there just in case others might want to contribute an answer.

Edit: just in case there really is a bug in the code that demonstrates the behavior, here it is (also related to the other question).  I've been running it in LinqPad, and sometimes I see all the `WriteLine` results, and sometimes I don't.  Please, no critiques of the code quality, I just want to see if I understand what is happening.  I suspect there might be something with that `[ThreadStatic]` modified variable.

```
static void Main() //Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] messages = "this is a test.  but it's going to be an issue!".Split(' ');

    try{
        messages.AsParallel().ForAll(Log);
    } catch(AggregateException){
        throw;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
[ThreadStatic]
static bool _disable = false;
public static void Log(string message)
{
    if (_disable)
    {
        return;
    }
    try {
        _disable = true;
        Console.WriteLine(GetPrefix() + message);
        throw new Exception("bar");
    } finally {
        _disable = false;
    }
}

public static string GetPrefix()
{
    Log("Getting prefix!");
    return "Prefix: ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I think it's confusing when you talk about tasks. What you have are iterations of a loop that will be executed in parallel using `Task`s, but that doesn't mean each iterations is a task.

Second, if you're really doing this just for logging, you're not likely to get any performance gain, I don't think logging is parallelizable.

Now, what you could do is to manually create a separate `Task` for each iteration of the loop and then wait for them to complete using `Task.WaitAll()`. This way, all iterations will be executed and if some of them fail, `WaitAll()` is going to throw an `AggregateException` containing them all.

```
var tasks = messages.Select(m => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Log(m)));
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

This is likely going to be less efficient that `Parallel.ForEach()` or PLINQ, but that may be okay for you. If not, then you have to use the `try`-`catch` approach you suggested.

Comment: First, I suppose this confusion does seem to be a source of my problem. Second, *while this use of Tasks for logging bothers me too*, the logging is only related to the odd requirements mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729907/circular-dependency-with-cross-cutting-concern/17731370#17731370 .

Comment: This `Task.WaitAll` does seem to be the answer to my question, although I wonder how different the workload of `Task.WaitAll` with each action given a separate task than the workload of `Parrallel.ForEach(xxx,action)` or `xxx.AsParallel().ForAll(action)` with actions apparently distributed between tasks.

Comment: @JayC You don't have to wonder. Write your real code both ways and then measure the difference.